# How does this equation hold in the proof of Jensen’s inequality?

Tags: information-theory

While reading the *Elements of Information Theory* (Cover &Thomas) on the page 27, I cannot understand why this function holds:  $p'_{i} = p_i/(1−p_k)$. Please help explain a bit. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k p_if(x_i)&=p_kf(x_k)+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_if(x_i)\\
&=p_kf(x_k)+(1-p_k)\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{p_i}{1-p_k}f(x_i)\\
&=p_kf(x_k)+(1-p_k)\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} p_i'f(x_i)\\
\end{align}

For convenience, he just defines $$p_i'=\frac{p_i}{1-p_k}.$$

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. So $p'_i$ is not a derivative. Am I right?

Comment: I got it. The first inequation in the original derivation is the assumption of the induction and the second inequation is the application of equation 2.77. And the reason why he defined $p'_i$ is to normalize the distribution without having the detached $p_k$ as @leonbloy said in his/her answer. Please screen my reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: yup, you are right. We usually use the term "inequality" rather than "inequation"

Comment: Yeh, "inequality" as in  "Jensen's inequality".

Answer (score 1):

The trick of defining $$p_i'=\frac{p_i}{1-p_k}$$
allows us to have a new probability function (for all the original points except the last one). We divide by ${1-p_k}$ (where $k$ is the last point) in order to normalize the distribution, so that it sums up to one.